# Sort a list of coordinates in c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm working with a lot of coordinates x & y.

```
   float x[6][2] = 
{{204.85099999999989,289.052},{1663.8270000000005,289.052},
{1663.8270000000005,-178.308},{204.85099999999989,-178.308},
{1298.0670000000002,-178.308},{1298.0670000000002,289.052}};
```

And basically, they're all linked with another points in this list but they're not sorted.

All these points are the coordinates of a geometric shape.
Each x and y corresponds to a point.

[image]

And I am looking for the logical order of the points. For example if I start from a random point. The next point must be the one where the x or the y correspond etc...

[image]

I want to sort the points like the image above.

I would like to know if there are existing algorithms to do this with a list of coordinates, or if you have to start from scratch. And in this case, do you have any advice for points with several segments?

UPDATE: i made a more readable example.

Comment: When you say "x or y correspond", what does that mean?  Is it based on the actual image, i.e. you need a pattern recognition algorithm?

Comment: Well, each point is "linked" with another point (maybe my list is wrong). So basically, if i have {1,2} {4,5}{2,5}, i would like something like that {1,2}{2,5}{5,2}. When i'm saying "x or y correspond", i'm just saying the good path @franji1.

Comment: I would say [Topological_sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), but you have to handle the "loop"

Comment: @Jarod42 but a topological sorting is not using the coordinates, no ?

Comment: You can see an edge as a dependency between the 2 points, so if all your edges are in correct direction (they are in given drawing, but reversing arrow from D2 to D5 would not, there are still workaround to handle that), you can use it to sort your points (or your edge according to their starting point).

Comment: That doesn't look sorted. Which point comes after D2? I see both D3 and D5. (Also, what if there is a point that is not connected to the others?) This seems like a path finding problem, not a sorting one.

Comment: @RaymondChen it's my main problem, i want to sort this coordinates.  technically D2 would be one of those two {1298.0670000000002,-178.308},{1298.0670000000002,289.052}}.

Comment: And even if i want to do a path finding with this, D2 would be a problem because it's not D2 to D2.1 but D2.1 (or D5) to D2.

Comment: It seems you are trying to find a [Hamiltonian cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) - a path that visits each vertex once. There are algorithms for that; they are all pretty complex, because the problem is hard.

Comment: Is it possible that D2 be connected to D6 or D4 instead of D5 ?

Comment: One simple solution could be you calculate the average of all your points. This average becomes the center of your new orthonormated mark, then you calcule the angle of each point in this mark. Finally you sort all the points according their angle.